# Where's this cwm and mountains in Nunavik, northern QC?

Tags: identify-this, quebec

[image]

I chanced upon this picture at [Nunavik, Northern Quebec : canada](https://old.reddit.com/r/canada/comments/g3v12v/nunavik_northern_quebec/).

> You can drive surprisingly far north though. [Lac Pac Water Aerodrome](https://goo.gl/maps/igQ8gPQbsJj8M7d66) Appears to be the furthest north in Quebec you can drive. Interestingly, you can now drive all the way to [Tuktoyaktuk](https://goo.gl/maps/tN4UfEeNssSs7NrN7) via car. I know what road trip I want to take now!

Can you drive to this location and just get out of your car to behold this vista?

Comment: If this really is in northern Quebec, then the probability that you can "just drive there" is almost exactly 0%.

Comment: What is a "cwn"? If that is a spelling mistake please correct.

Comment: @KristvanBesien:  A cwm is another word for a [cirque.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirque)  Also, your post is a fine example of [Muphry's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thanks. Learned a couple of things...

Comment: BTW Tuktoyaktuk is not in Quebec, as someone on Reddit clarified

Comment: In Welsh, cwm means "valley" and w is a vowel. Pronounced roughly "coom". I was unaware it was a technical term for a highly specific type of valley.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's on the Koroc River in [Kuururjuaq National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuururjuaq_National_Park), in the [Torngat Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torngat_Mountains), in the far northeast of Quebec.

You can't drive there, as [Michael Seifert already answered](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/156779/47922). The only way in I saw was by plane, from Quebec City or Montreal to Kuujjuaq, then to Kangiqsualujjuaq.

---

#### Research

Reddit user [xJoeCanadian](https://old.reddit.com/user/xJoeCanadian) wrote [in a comment](https://old.reddit.com/r/onguardforthee/comments/g3lbnw/unknown_landscapes_of_canada_nunavik_northern/fntywju/) on the same image:

> This is Torngait [sic] Mountains and the Koroc River! My ancestors have known this land for thousands of years, and I worked there too. Love this place.

Here's a Nunavik Parks page that uses [a very similar image](http://docs.nunavikparks.ca/SiteCollectionImages/Experiences/Contenu/PNK%20Forfait%202017%20Hiver%20Qurlutuarjuq/PNK%20%282107%29%20%28c%29%20Martin%20L%C3%A9vesques.jpg): [Follow the Inuit's Footsteps in the Torngats](http://www.nunavikparks.ca/en/experiences/follow-the-inuits-footsteps-in-the-torngats). Other Nunavik Parks pages have pictures of the same location:

[image: wider view]
[source](http://www.nunavikparks.ca/en/parks/kuururjuaq) -- photo credit Ulysse Lefebvre

[image: view more to the right]
[source](https://www.facebook.com/parcsnunavik/photos/a.653885194753232/1072557979552616/?type=3) -- *"Parc National Kuururjuaq, mars 2018. crédit photo: Aubrey Claude-Desroches"*. Translation: "Kuururjuaq National Park, March 2018. Photo credit: Aubrey Claude-Desroches". **More**: [another](https://www.facebook.com/parcsnunavik/photos/a.653885194753232/1072558149552599/?type=3&theater), [other side of the valley](https://www.facebook.com/parcsnunavik/photos/a.653885194753232/1072558052885942/?type=3&theater), [head-on view of the mountain valley](https://www.facebook.com/parcsnunavik/photos/a.653885194753232/868575773284172/?type=3&theater)

[image: view more to the left]
[source](http://www.nunavikparks.ca/iu/experiences/follow-the-inuits-footsteps-in-the-torngats) under "Day 6" -- photo credit Julie Dyotte

Here's the same place in the summer:
[image: summer]
[source](http://www.nunavikparks.ca/en/experiences/conquer-diberville-summit) under "Day 3" -- photo credit Catherine Le Gall-​​​Marchand

I also found [this panorama on Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/kVxPyfXHpjCeg31Q8) that seems to be **in** the mountain valley, though it's not marked on the right spot on the map. The exact spot seems to be [here](https://goo.gl/maps/Pa6xX1uGew7pG6qL8), meaning the other photos are taken on the other side of the valley looking south.

---

Now, if you really did want to drive somewhere in northern Quebec, you can drive to the [Radisson dam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert-Bourassa_generating_station), which is on James Bay

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea precisely where the vista is, but assuming it's actually in Nunavik, I can answer the last part of your question:

> Can you drive to this location and just get out of your car to behold this vista?

No.  According to [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nunavik)

> There are no road links between Nunavik and southern Quebec, although the Trans-Taiga Road of the Jamésie region ends near the 55th parallel on the Caniapiscau Reservoir, several hundred kilometers south of Kuujjuaq.

The Nunavik region comprises all of Quebec north of the 55th parallel;  the Lac Pau Water Aerodrome, mentioned in your question, is near the end of the Trans-Taiga Road.